# Build a column based on Datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a datetime index (hourly period for 1 year),and based on an hour range and weekday (ex: Monday, from 00:00:00 to 02:00:00), I want to add only one column (Tarif) with a specific value (constant).

For now I have this:

vazio= 0.065725
cheia= 0.070622

```
                   Potência Ativa  ...  
2019-01-01 00:00:00            31.0  ...               
2019-01-01 01:00:00            26.0  ...                    
2019-01-01 02:00:00            21.0  ...                      
2019-01-01 03:00:00            21.0  ...                      
2019-01-01 04:00:00            21.0  ...
```

and I want to turn into this:

```
                   Potência Ativa  ...       Tarif
2019-01-01 00:00:00            31.0  ...     0.065725          
2019-01-01 01:00:00            26.0  ...      0.065725              
2019-01-01 02:00:00            21.0  ...      0.070622                
2019-01-01 03:00:00            21.0  ...      0.070622                
2019-01-01 04:00:00            21.0  ...      0.070622
```

Shall I create a new Datetimeindex and when finished copy the column to the existing dataframe. Or shall I work directly on the current dataframe?
Any ideas where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work directly with the existing dataframe and add a new column using numpy [`select`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

Example for Mondays 0:00 through 2:00 0.065725, else 0.070622:

```
df['Tarif'] = np.select([(df.index.hour<=2) & (df.index.weekday==0)], [0.065725], 0.070622)
```

You can add further conditions to the first list of `select` and corresponding values to the second list. Don't forget the parantheses as `&` and `|` take precedence over `>`, `==` etc.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible instead of Monday, I compare it with every business day? I tried with index.weekday == 'B' but I go the following warning: "FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead". It seems, index.weekday only works with integers.

Comment: e.g. `(df.index.weekday>=0) & (df.index.weekday<=4)` for Monday through Friday.

Comment: Is there a clear solution for this:consumption_year['Tarif'] = np.select([(consumption_year.index.hour<=2)
                                        & ((consumption_year.index.weekday==0)
                                        | (consumption_year.index.weekday==1)
                                        | (consumption_year.index.weekday==2)
                                        | (consumption_year.index.weekday==3)
                                        | (consumption_year.index.weekday==4))], [0.065725], 0)

Comment: yes, see my previous comment: `np.select([(consumption_year.index.hour<=2) & (df.index.weekday>=0) & (df.index.weekday<=4)], [0.065725], 0)`

Answer (score 0):

I also would like to limit this condition between those 2 periods:

```
df['Tarif'] = np.select([(df.index.hour<=2) & (df.index.weekday==0)], [0.065725], 0.070622)
```

Winter: 01-01-2019 to 31-03-2019 and 01-11-2019 to 31-12-2019

Summer: 01-04-2019 to 31-10-2019

I was thinking if .grouby can help?

Comment: Don't post further question as anwers please. If it is a small modification edit you original question, if it's a larger change ask a new question.

Comment: you can include the date in the condition

Comment: How can I add a date condition? for example 01-04-2019 to 31-10-2019, I tried index.date, and index.day, but the first receives a numpy.ndarray and the second, I believe when I use an integer, it enters in conflict with the previous index.weekday.

Comment: `(df.index>=pd.to_datetime('2019-04-01')) & (df.index<=pd.to_datetime('2019-10-31'))`

Comment: On my case, month also worked. Thank you very much! consumption_year.index.month >= 4